# How to stop an Observable interval manually?

Tags: angular

I am currently trying to make a 20 second timer like this:

```
this.timer = Observable.interval(1000).take(20).map((tick) => tick+1).subscribe((tick) => {
    this.reverseTimer = 20-tick;
})
```

This is fine if I let the Observable reach 20 every time, but sometimes, I want to end the timer early. Right now, I can't stop the timer until it stops itself after 20 seconds.

Right now, I am hiding the timer in the display when I want it to stop, but I need it to be able to restart. If I try to restart the timer before 20 seconds, `reverseTimer` flickers between the new timer and old timer values because I haven't stopped the old timer.

I have tried `this.timer.unsubscribe()` but I get the error that `unsubscribe` does not exist for timer.

Comment: Try the `takeUntil` operator. It take another observable as the parameter. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/takeuntil.md

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look to the [Timer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html) operator. You can create an Observable that emits a particular item after a given delay. You can easily create your countdown system.

In this example, I will create a timer and then stop it after 5 seconds.

```
const start = 20;

const source = Rx.Observable
  .timer(1000, 1000)
  .map(tick => start - tick)
  .take(start + 1)
  .subscribe(tick => console.log(tick));


setTimeout(() => {
  //Stop the timer
  source.unsubscribe();
}, 5000);
```

You can see the [**Working plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/456bwnJThtut86p3TDlF)

Answer (score 4):

If `unsubscribe` does not exist on the result you've received from your call to `subscribe`, you are likely using RxJS 4. In which case, you will have received an `IDisposable` instance and should call `dispose` to stop the timer:

```
this.timer.dispose();
```